# Automatically rotate AppSync API key

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

CloudFormation provides an [AWS::AppSync::ApiKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appsync-apikey.html) resource type for creating an AppSync API key in a CloudFormation stack. The API key will expire. Is there a simple way to define a rotation schedule within CloudFormation? I don't see anything, but it seems like such an obvious use case that I'm not sure what good the AWS::AppSync::ApiKey resource type is without it.

Currently I have a lambda that runs on a schedule to generate a new key and store it in SecretsManager. This works, but it's an extra step, and I have to run the lambda manually the first time. I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? @thom-smith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t want to create an `AWS::AppSync::ApiKey`. Instead make a `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret` and a `AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule`. The RotationSchedule will let you use a lambda to automatically rotate the ApiKey and store it in the Secret.

Ultimately, the `AWS::AppSync::ApiKey` is of little practical use for you because you will need to deal with the expiration.